# Google App Engine SpringBoot JSR-356 support unavailable Exception

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to convert a springboot project to run on GAE. So far, I am able to connect the project to cloud sql locally.

However, when making the conversion to app engine standard(to deploy it) following several guides/tutorials such as

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4

I see the following exception whenever I start the GAE dev server, or deploy.

```
    [INFO] GCLOUD: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:193)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:274)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:368)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
```

Since I can run the project using embedded Jetty just fine, I think it is a configuration/pom problem. More specifically, I know that JSR 356, Websocket api is not supported in app engine. However, what I do not see is how my current project relies on websocket, as I don't remember configuring websocket, or using it in the project at all...

Could someone please look at my pom.xml and point out if there are any websocket dependencies that I am unaware of?

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- google map services -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- db related-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure why the websocket error occurred, but for me it was fixed by doing the following 2 steps:

1 Upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent version

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

2 Delete Target folder